# Why does Xamarin Forms uses one Activity for all Pages

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Xamarin Forms uses one Activity for rendering all the Pages. Basically a Page is an Android child view or fragment. Why not have each Page be an Activity? This is in contrast with how Xamarin forms does it for iOS. On iOS, a Page is a UIViewController.

I'm NOT asking how Xamarin Forms works in Android (it uses fragments).

Why did Xamarin choose to do this? I believe there are some architectural choices?

Answer (score 0):

Someone correct me if I'm mistaken, I think Xamarin.Forms started before the backporting of fragments on Android but is written in a fashion similar to how fragments work using views.

However, I think this has changed if you are using `AppCompat` and a `FormsAppCompatActivity` as your MainActivity, which now does use a native Android `Fragment` to hold a Forms page.

My best guess as to why it was done this way is for better memory management and to ensure that any views or objects that are no longer being used are properly disposed of. Also, as to why `Activity` isn't used for a `Page` it's probably because it made creating navigation easier to have it all done within Xamarin.Forms itself and not natively. For example, when using a `TabbedPage` it was probably easier to add a forms page, that is a view, into a fragment for use by a native Android `ActionBar` than trying to use a form page if each page was a separate activity.

Comment: Yes, I think they are using fragments, but that's not what my question. My question is why isn't any Page an Activity on Android, just how a Page is a UIViewController on iOS? There's a lot of code in the Xamarin Forms Android which updates dynamically the Activity bar elements: arrow button, title, option buttons, each depending on the current Page. Why doing all that work for Android but not for iOS?

Comment: I updated my answer but really without asking a Xamarin employee, who worked on it personally, why it was implemented that way it's really just a guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

at some point in the past, Google was promoting this pattern as a standard to develop Android apps.

It's more of an Architecture design.

Benefits:

- Sharing state between activities is harder than doing it between fragments.
- Better support for animation when transitioning between fragments than between activities.
- easier Sharing data between Activities
- Easy deep linking

You can get more information from the following links

[Modernize Your Android App With The Single Activity Pattern](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/modernize-your-android-app-with-the-single-activity-pattern-1526407a7d4)

[Reasons to use Android Single-Activity Architecture with Navigation Component](https://oozou.com/blog/reasons-to-use-android-single-activity-architecture-with-navigation-component-36)

I honestly feel your question should be "Why Single Activity Architecture preferred Over Multiple Activity Architecture"  you should get more answers